# Dividing both sides problem in ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving for differential equation of a general equation of circles .

Eqn: $x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$

[image]

I do not understand after the highlighted step, how the term $y^2$ can be shifted in the denominator. **Can't it be $0$ ?**